# Django Rest Framework multiple field upload with serializers.FileField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload multiple files through and API using DRF.

It works, what I want is created, but I don't understand why it always ends in an error. I currently handle it with a `try/except` which seems to do the job until I find an answer.

Here is the error: `TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Here are some snippets of my current code (Giveaway and GiveawayMedia are 2 models which should be straight forward from the code below):

```
class GiveawayViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = SimpleGiveawaySerializer  # Irrelevant to this question
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return GiveawayPostSerializer

    # /giveaways - POST
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        return Response("Created - Giveaway created.")
```

```
class GiveawayPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    media = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Giveaway
        read_only_fields = ["id"]
        fields = [
            "id",
            "media",
            # more fields
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_giveaway = Giveaway.objects.create(...)  # other fields to create here
        if "media" in validated_data:
            for m in validated_data["media"]:
                GiveawayMedia.objects.create(giveaway=new_giveaway, media=m)
        new_giveaway.save()
        return new_giveaway
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\Desktop\Hatless\WinAway\WinAway%20-%20API\api\viewsets.py", line 130, in create
    super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 20, in create
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 562, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 529, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Users\sorin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1692, in to_representation
    return [self.child.to_representation(item) if item is not None else None for item in data]
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

And models:

```
class Giveaway(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other bunch of irrelevant fields to the question.

class GiveawayMedia(models.Model):
    giveaway = models.ForeignKey(Giveaway, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="media")
    media = models.FileField()
```

Comment: Can you include the `Giveaway` model and `GiveawayMedia` model?

Comment: Please also include the full stacktrace. It'll be helpful in determining which line is causing the error.

Comment: @schillingt i included the stacktrace and models

Comment: Can you run a debugger to figure out what model/field `RelatedManager` is for?

Comment: It works without error when I take out the media serializer field `media = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField(), required=False)` and any reference to it.

Comment: Can you try renaming the `media` field on the serializer to `media_files`? I think DRF is having a conflict with trying to resolve the differences.

Comment: You are correct, `media` seemed to have conflicted with the related field `media` in the models. Thanks for pointing out. If you write this as an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: Please post the `SimpleGiveawaySerializer`. As the error occurs when returning the response, `SimpleGiveawaySerializer` can be the point of error.